# How to return a string value from Python to objective-c

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have a python script, which doesn't return a value, that is run from a cocoa app using:

```
PyRun_SimpleFileEx(mainFile, script_path, 1)
```

and this works fine.

My new script will now return a string value.
How can I get my cocoa app to get this return value as an NSString?

Answer (score 0):

By sring value I understand a char*. So the. You can initialize a string with:

```
char* charstr=PyRun_SimpleFileEx(mainFile, script_path, 1);

NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:charstr]];
```

Comment: PyRun_SimpleFileEx returns an int indicating success or failure of the function. I'm trying to find which python function to call so that I can get the return value as a char (and then an NSString).

Comment: i think you can use PyRun_FileEx(...) which returns PyObject* . from there you could extract desired char*